# How much of this code should be inside the UI Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

So I have an `AsyncTask` doing some work in the background. The work is actually a list of commands that are done in a for loop. All commands may run the following method (inside the for loop):

```
public void print() {
    // Create and add a TextView
    // Variable "c" is the Activity reference, I get it in the constructor by passing "this" from the Activity
    TextView tv = new TextView(c);
    // Set its text
    tv.setText(text);
    // Set the style
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setTextSize(fontSize);
    tv.setSingleLine(false);
    // Add it to the linear layout
    display.addView(tv);
    // Add a spacer
    View spacer = new View(c);
    // Set bg color
    spacer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0x88, 0, 0, 0));
    // Set width and height
    spacer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, separatorHeight));
    // Add it to the layout
    display.addView(spacer);
    // Screen should update
    displayChanged = true;
}
```

At the end of the for loop I have this line:

```
if (displayChanged) updateScreen();
```

And finally the `updateScreen()` method:

```
private void updateScreen() {
    // Surround the linear layout with a vertical scroll view
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(c);
    scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    scrollView.addView(display);
    // Set code background color
    scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA));
    // Finally, display everything
    c.setContentView(scrollView);
    // Screen shouldn't update again
    displayChanged = false;
}
```

As you can see, both methods (`print` and `updateScreen`) work with views and `updateScreen` also does a `setContentView`. Now I want to run as much of this code in the `AsyncTask` background thread. So how much of this code should be in a `runOnUiThread(... code here ...)`?

Comment: *Now I want to run as much of this code in the AsyncTask background thread.*, Why?

Comment: Because a lot of work on the UI thread may make the user interface slow.

Comment: Updating the UI (views) must be in the UI thread, otherwise your app will crash.

Comment: @PatriX1996 So both methods should be in the UI Thread completely or only the `setContentView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `displayChanged` in a background thread. The rest of the code uses the UI toolkit and accessing this in anything but the UIThread is considered unsafe and not recommended by Google according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Comment: Thanks! The documentation link helped me! So instantiating / accessing any view must be in the UI Thread.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But if you are iterating over a list and creating a lot of new textviews (rows?) you might be better of using a ListView or RecyclerView coupled with an adapter.

Comment: If you read the documentation for the listview you will find that you can set a divider drawable that will automatically be added between the items. And if this is not enough you can easily inflate a custom layout in the adapter.